# unchecked input for loop condition

Tags: java, security, checkmarx

I am getting unchecked input for loop condition at below lines in my code.

```
String FirstName= request.getParameter("FirstName") !=null ?request.getParameter("FirstName"):"";
```

I have provided below solutions but checkmarx scan still showing same error.

```
if(!FirstName.equals("")){
FirstName=ESAPI.validator().getValidInput("requestParameter",FirstName,"HTTPParameterValue", 2000, true);
}
```

I have used getValidinteger() method also but both didn't seems to resolve the issue.

Here is for loop--

```
ArrayList<String> userDetails = UserData.getDetails(FirstName);

for(int i=0;i<=userDetails.size();i++){
   String rollno=userDetails.get(0)!=null?userDetails.get(0):"";
   String subject=userDetails.get(1)!=null?userDetails.get(1):"";
}
```

Comment: Where is the "for loop"?

Comment: That's not your actual code as it wouldn't compile: the keyword `for` is wrong

Comment: I have complied my code if you have any solution then advise.

Answer (score 0):

While the **userDetails.size** doesn't seemed to be something that a malicious user can control or influence (*seeing **UserData.getDetails** would only provide a fix set of items*), it is still a good idea to validate the userDetails.size for any potential risk that the size may inadvertently increase to a very large number, causing a Denial of Service.

So instead of validating the Firstname, it should be the size of the Arraylist that is checked

```
static final int MAXSIZE = 2000;
int arraySize = userDetails.size(); 
if (arraySize > MAXSIZE) { // todo  }

for(int i=0;arraySize;i<=i++){
   String rollno=userDetails.get(0)!=null?userDetails.get(0):"";
   String subject=userDetails.get(1)!=null?userDetails.get(1):"";
}
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for your solutions, Even if we provide the solution like above checkmarx scan still show the same error. Could you please provide some solution ,so that this error will resolve in checkmarx scan.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of arraySize in for loop, use an iterator to loop through the array. This will fix the issue.

Comment: Checkmarx also checks `while(iterator.hasNext())` loops the same way, so that will not solve the problem.